# In getstram.io, is it a good design to add custom data to an activity

Tags: getstream-io

I am experimenting with getstream.io to implement feeds and timelines.  I am wondering what is the best approach between simply using actors and objects that are keys to a database or storing more data in the activity.
For example, let’s say that I want to add activity to my user feed represented by:

```
Actor: ‘user_1´,
Verb: ‘post’,
Object: ‘note_3’
```

Where ´user_1´ and ´note_3´ refers to objects in my application.  When retrieving the activities to render them in the UI, I could fetch ´user_1’ from my database to get more details like a picture URL and name.  That involves fetching a lot data for each activity.  Or I could store more data into the activity by adding custom data such as ´user_url’ and ´user_name or the entire user object.

Has anyone faced the same question?  What is the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_Since this answer was originally provided, Stream added a new feature called [Collections](https://getstream.io/docs/#collections_introduction) which presents a new and potentially preferable approach.

---

Both are feasible although the use of identifiers and an [enrichment](https://getstream.io/docs/#enrichment_introduction) step that incorporates additional data from your backend services is the preferred approach.

Keeping activities 'light weight' minimises latency and network transit times.

There is also a limit to the size of activities; plenty for some additional text fields or counters/values, but not enough to feasibly store base64 encoded images or other binary data.

The docs also provide suggestions on [what to store](https://getstream.io/docs/#what-to-store).

Comment: Thanks.  I had not gone that far in the documentation.  Enrichment is the way I was thinking of going.

Comment: Stream have updated their docs. That topic broken link appears to now be covered by https://getstream.io/docs/#enrichment_introduction